# retrieve Value from SQL Table using powerapp

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

I have 3 form inside the screen which are

1. Period form
   It display a period

- (that table have a field 'aphid')

2. Activity form
   It display the Activity Sequence and Description

- (that table have a field 'actid')

3. Week Form

- I want to retrieve the value from this app_apWeek table using the key
  period form (app_apHead) and activity form(app_activity)

which select apwprogress from aphid ='some value' and actid ='somevalue'

sample code that can retrieve a value =
select apwprogress from app_apweek where actID=235 and aphID =23

**Summary : i want to retreive the apwProgress field from app_apweek table**

I have some problem of retrieve value from multiple field. I am using Lookup but give an error on it.

```
LookUp(
    // Look for app_apWeek table
    app_apWeek,
    // Using apHead table(aphid) and activity table(actid) to look for the value
    app_apHead.aphID And app_activity.actID,
    // Replace the value to the textinput1 field
    TextInput1
    )
```

[image: Progress Field value]

SQL table value

[image: SQL]

I not sure which part is wrong. Can suggest to me a better way to retrieve value. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: i try to modified the field you gave, it still cant get the 'value' of 20 after click in it.

Comment: It's difficult for me to tell what the issue is through screenshots alone. Some things to try: **1.** Hover over the blue error and determine what the actual error message is (my guess is "delegation warning"). Research this warning. **2.** Ensure the `app_apHead` and `app_activity` values within the `And` statement are the *control names* (Textbox, Combobox, etc.) from your app. They look like *table names*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little confused as to what exactly you are trying to do, but this should get you there.

**Looking at the SQL statement...**

`SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <column1> = 235 AND <column2> = 23`

**Here's one way to do this in PowerApps:**

```
LookUp(TEST_TABLE,                    //SELECT the first record
    And(                              //WHERE, AND
        actID = Value(txtActID.Text), //column1 = txtActID.Text as INT
        aphID = Value(txtAphID.Text)  //column = txtAphID.Text as INT
    )
)
```

**Where...**

- `actID` and `aphID` are `INT` data types in SQL and...
- `txtActID` and `txtAphID` are `Textbox` controls in PowerApps

**See it in action...**

[image]

**Things to remember:**

- Using a `LookUp` here will only bring back *the first* record even though more records may meet the criteria
- Use the PowerApps `Filter` function instead if there are more than 1 record that meets the criteria

Comment: SeaDude perfectly answered your question. I don't see what your comment is adding to either the answer or your question?

Comment: may be my question not that clear. he point me the way to retrieve whole set of record, but actually i wish is retreive the apwProgress field from app_apweek table, i not familiar the way using powerapp call SQL script~

Comment: Thank you Iona-Varga! Its ok @Desmond-Sim, PowerApps issues can be difficult to explain (I have ~4 years experience working with them! It's taken me a long time to speak with clarity on these issues). I'd suggest you try to generalize the issue further and break it down into smaller chunks. Then come back **with a new question** and we can try to assist.

Comment: Thanks Seadude. I try using Gallery Method to retrieve the value, don't use Form field to retrieve successfully get the data.